# How to enable "typing" on selection widget in Odoo?

Tags: odoo-8, odoo, odoo-view

I have used a selection widget in my program and it has lot of items in the drop down. Is there any method to enable typing on it so user can select item easily. (just like making a JComboBox editable in java)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you are using the `many2one` field with the `widget="selection"`, you can select the selection box by clicking it and you start typing what you are looking for, the box change to the value that you are writing. By the way, you must write it fast and the drop down must not be deployed.

The other option is to use a `many2one` field without the selection widget. You can install the community module [web_m2x_options](https://www.odoo.com/apps/modules/7.0/web_m2x_options/) and use the `limit` attibute to avoid the option "Search More". Like this you can write in the box to find the elements. For example, you can show until 10 elements without the option "Search More" with this example:

```xml
<field name="example_id" options="{'create': False, 'create_edit': False, 'limit': 10}" />
```

Comment: That's not working :(   And it wont be user friendly isn't it?

Comment: How many values are you using in the selection field? If they are many values maybe it is a good idea to make a `many2one` field, and you can write in this kind of field

Comment: It should be work what I told you. It's not very user friendly, but many programs work like that. I tried it in Chromium and Firefox and it work fine

Comment: Thanks. Actually its a many2one field and I added widget="selection" in the view xml. Because "Search More" link should not appear in the drop down. What I see is selection widget just select the first item starting from the key we press. It works for the 1st letter only. If there are many entries begin from same letter it doesn't help

Comment: I edited my answer @javatar. Check if now the second part of the answer suits to your needs :)