# How to show all the records in the widget selection in Odoo?

Tags: widget, selection, odoo-8, odoo

I have a view modified, and I have been changes. I have this widget:

```xml
<field name="country_id" position="attributes">
    <attribute name="widget">selection</attribute>
</field>
```

This widget cut the records in Hungry, how to show all records?

Answer (score 1):

Check the answer I wrote [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32310071/odoo-enable-type-on-selection-widget/32310223#32310223). You can user the module `web_m2x_options` instead of the widget selection and write the field like this

```xml
<field name="example_id" options="{'create': False, 'create_edit': False, 'limit': 10}" />
```

Comment: It works, but not show scroll and it is very long, is possible with scroll?

Comment: I don't think so, but you can use the "Search more..." option as well